# separating concerns with jquery-mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a table in my jquery mobile 1.4.5 index.html page:

```
<table id="summary-table" data-role="table" 
       data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
     <thead>
        ...
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        ...
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I also have some javascript in my index.js file:

```
    $(document).on("touchend", "#listButton", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        db.allDocs({include_docs: true, attachments: true}, function(err, response) { 
           for (var record in response) {
              $("#summary-table tbody").append(
                  "<tr>"+
                  "<th>" + record.a + "</th>"+
                  "<td>" + record.b + "</td>"+
                  "</tr>");
           }
    });
```

This will work, but doesn't seem to be a good way for seperating concerns as I am embedding html in my javascript.

What is the best practise for separating concerns with jquery mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I followed the pattern used in the example project https://github.com/hazems/cordova-mega-app

That project separates the javascript code into the following concerns:

- api (services)
- model
- controller